If $A+B=AB$, Does it imply $A$, $B$ Commute?


If $A+B=AB$, Does it imply $A$, $B$ Commute?


What I did is $$A+B=AB \Rightarrow I-A-B+AB=I \Rightarrow (I-A)(I-B)=I$$
Since $I-A, I-B$ are inverses of each other we have $$(I-B)(I-A)=I \Rightarrow B+A=BA$$
So we have $A+B=AB=BA$
Is this universally TRUE?

Yes, see here and here and here and here, and  here is a generalization

Your argument is correct.
